# Do all black holes have the same mass density?

Tags: black-holes, mass, spacetime, density, singularities

I have been reading about black holes in Stephan Hawking's 'A Brief History of Time'. Then I was reading more about it on Wikipedia; I am making a school project on it. I do not really remember what made me ask this question, ie. whether all black holes have the same mass density. But, then I also saw (or saw again, because that book has it too) the 'No-Hair Theorem' which states that 'all black hole solutions of the Einstein-Maxwell equations of gravitation and electromagnetism in general relativity can be completely characterized by only three externally observable classical parameters: mass, electric charge, and angular momentum.' - Wikipedia. So, it doesn't look like the mass-density with change for a black hole. Would it? Do all black holes have the same mass-densities or not?